# Remove objects from array/hash which is only referenced from that array/hash

Tags: ruby, object-reference

#### Is it possible to remove objects from an array/hash which is only referenced from this array/hash?

Example of what I am looking for:

```
some_array.reject!{|elm| ObjectSpace.only_one_reference_to?(elm)}
```

I am making a script which seem to be growing quickly in the ram. The reason why is is a long-living array which keeps obsolete objects around event though it does not need to.

The problem is essentially this:

```
@@long_living_array = []
class Foo
    def initialize
        @@long_living_array << self
    end
end

a = Foo.new()
b = Foo.new()
a = nil
#Here is the problem, a sticks around in @@long_living_array, even though it does not really need to be there.
```

Thus, my real task is to iterate over the `@@long_living_array` and remove any objects which is only referenced from this array. (And yes, I do need the array.)

---

I believe it could be solved if I was able to find all references to an object, and then remove the object if the reference in the array is the only one. Thus I have been looking for something along the lines of

```
a = Foo.new
all_references_to_a = ObjectSpace.get_all_references(a)
```

I have found [this article](https://cirw.in/blog/find-references) which seems to do something similar, but it is a patch to Ruby itself (some C files) so it is not possible for me to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the object itself, you could store a [`WeakRef`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/weakref/rdoc/WeakRef.html). It allows the referenced object to be garbage-collected:

```
require 'weakref'

@@long_living_array = []

class Foo
  def initialize
    @@long_living_array << WeakRef.new(self)
  end
end

a = Foo.new
b = Foo.new
@@long_living_array.count
#=> 2

a = nil                                       # reassign 'a'
GC.start                                      # start the garbage collector
@@long_living_array.keep_if(&:weakref_alive?) # remove GC'ed objects

@@long_living_array.count
#=> 1
```

Comment: Nice usecase of `weakref`.

Comment: Cool! I will try this out as soon as I can!